# windows phone - modify grouped observable collection

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8, observablecollection, grouped-collection-select

I have a grouped observable collection:

```
ObservableCollection<Group<ViewModel>> items
```

which is a datasource for a LongListSelector. I want to add / remove items to it.
I tried things like:

```
items.Where(group => group.Contains(item)).First().Remove(item); // didn't work
items.Where(group => group.Title.Equals("a")).First().add(item) // also didn't work
```

I tried removing the whole group, and re-inserting it again, but with no avail.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Does `Group` implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`? Does `ViewModel` implement `INorifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: ViewModel yes, but Group no, actually Group is an implementation of  List<T>. But regardless, it is an observable collection of groups of ViewModel, if we considered the observing criteria is for the group and not for the view models then the INorifyPropertyChanged should be triggered when I remove a group or insert new one .. or am I wrong ?

Comment: Yes, inserting/removing should be enough.

Comment: then I think the way I'm inserting and deleting is wrong. Maybe the Where query returns a clone of the collection and not the original one..

Answer (score 1):

LINQ functions like `Where` always return *new* collection which isn't linked to the original one. To remove groups, use the following approach.

```
foreach (var group in items.Where(group => group.Contains(item).ToList())
    items.Remove(group)
```

Also, if the `Group` class doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, adding/removing items to the group will have no effect.